# Mac Terminal Disabling Lid Sleep

Tags: macos, terminal, sh

I need a way to disable lid sleep through a command in terminal, without root/admin access.
Any ideas?

Comment: This seems off-topic for SO. Maybe you should post it on http://superuser.com/!

Comment: why batch-file tag? batch is a windows thing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You could try the caffeinate command, which you can read about [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/caffeinate.8.html).

Comment: In which case, no you will need root access. I have come across programs that will do what you want, but they install a kernel extension.